# stop body width bigger than screen size

Tags: css

I am trying to setup my CSS but i have found the body size is bigger than my screen size, which means everything else becomes slightly out of place. I have tried width 100% and 100vw but still get the same results
You can see in the image below the border on the right has disappeared and there is a scroll bar along the bottom.

```
body{
   border: solid;
   width: 100%;  //or 100vw
}
```

[image]

just to add the only way to bright this in is to do width at 99%. Is this normal practice

Answer (score 1):

By default, `body` has some margin attached to it. Assign `margin: 0` and `overflow-x: hidden` to the body will fix this problem.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: solid;
  width: 100%;  //or 100vw

  /* if you want to add some gaps between the edge of the screen, use padding instead */
  padding-left: 2px;
}
```

Also, since you have `border` assigned to the body. It's better to change the `box-sizing` to `border-box` to all your element by default, otherwise your border will be cut off if you assign `width: 100%` to your `body`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: This did not work. It removed the margin on the left which was about 2px but the border is still beyond the screen. I only added the border to show what was happening. This will be removed

Comment: Instead of `margin`, it's better to use `padding`(`padding-left: 2px`) since it counts as content-box. so it won't have overflowed the x-axis on your page, or just remove `width: 100%` from your `body`